# Hi, I need to install the Weblogic Server without the admin rights

Tags: weblogic

I tried to install 12.1.3 version in my local but ended up with an issue. Please help me install it without admin rights as I don't get access of admin rights.[java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WBt3.png)

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible. A solution could be to use a Linux VM in your Windows host.

Comment: Hi Collin, the problem is i am having windows vm only and don't have any admin rights. Won't it be possible without admin rights?

Comment: Admin rights are required under Windows...

Comment: You could use a Virtual Machine or a Docker Container to obtain a local environment where you are admin.

Comment: you can use "Zip distribution Update 3 for Mac OSX, Windows, and Linux
(190 MB)"